# N+1 issue on bidirectional one-to-one with Jpa and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one, select-n-plus-1

The query being executed is:

```
from PurchaseOrder o join fetch o.basket where o.statusE in (:statuses)
```

Mapping in PurchaseOrder:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name="basket_id")
public ShoppingBasket getBasket() {
    return this.basket;
}
```

Mapping in ShoppingBasket:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "basket", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
public PurchaseOrder getOrder() {
    return order;
}
```

When that query is executed it's translated into the following queries:

-- 1 query of the following type, retrieving all the baskets and orders for the given status

```
select PurchaseOrder.*, ShoppingBasket.* /* changed for simplicity */
from purchaseorders purchaseor0_ 
    inner join shoppingbaskets shoppingba1_ on purchaseor0_.basket_id=shoppingba1_.id 
where purchaseor0_.status in (? , ? , ?) 
order by purchaseor0_.created DESC limit ?
```

-- n queries of the following type, one for each basket result on the previous query to retrieve the associated order

```
select pPurchaseOrder.* /* changed for simplicity */
from purchaseorders purchaseor0_ 
where purchaseor0_.basket_id=?
```

I tried changing the fetch strategy (I know it's ignored using HQL anyway), changing the fetch plan, and the 'optional' attribute out of desperation.
Is there any way to make Hibernate load the PurchaseOrders with the associated ShoppingBaskets in a single query? Do I have to use byte code instrumentation to achieve that and if so, how?

The Hibernate debug log is as follows:

```
DEBUG JDBCTransaction - begin
DEBUG ConnectionManager - opening JDBC connection
DEBUG JDBCTransaction - current autocommit status: true
DEBUG JDBCTransaction - disabling autocommit
DEBUG QueryTranslatorImpl - parse() - HQL: from com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder o join fetch o.basket where o.statusE in (:statuses) ORDER BY o.created DESC
DEBUG AST - --- HQL AST ---
 \-[QUERY] Node: 'query'
    +-[SELECT_FROM] Node: 'SELECT_FROM'
    |  \-[FROM] Node: 'from'
    |     +-[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
    |     |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |     |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |     |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |     |  |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |     |  |  |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |     |  |  |  |  |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'com'
    |     |  |  |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'ng'
    |     |  |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'ticketlogic'
    |     |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'core'
    |     |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'shop'
    |     |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'PurchaseOrder'
    |     |  \-[ALIAS] Node: 'o'
    |     \-[JOIN] Node: 'join'
    |        +-[FETCH] Node: 'fetch'
    |        \-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |           +-[IDENT] Node: 'o'
    |           \-[IDENT] Node: 'basket'
    +-[WHERE] Node: 'where'
    |  \-[IN] Node: 'in'
    |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |     |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'o'
    |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'statusE'
    |     \-[IN_LIST] Node: 'inList'
    |        \-[COLON] Node: ':'
    |           \-[IDENT] Node: 'statuses'
    \-[ORDER] Node: 'ORDER'
       +-[DOT] Node: '.'
       |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'o'
       |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'created'
       \-[DESCENDING] Node: 'DESC'

DEBUG ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
DEBUG HqlSqlBaseWalker - select << begin [level=1, statement=select]
DEBUG FromElement - FromClause{level=1} :  com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder (o) -> purchaseor0_
DEBUG FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  o -> purchaseor0_.id
DEBUG DotNode - getDataType() : basket -> org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType(com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket)
DEBUG DotNode - dereferenceEntityJoin() : generating join for basket in com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder {no alias} parent = [ {null} ]
DEBUG FromElement - FromClause{level=1} :  com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket (no alias) -> shoppingba1_
DEBUG FromClause - addJoinByPathMap() : o.basket -> FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=null,role=null,tableName=shoppingbaskets,tableAlias=shoppingba1_,origin=purchaseorders purchaseor0_,columns={purchaseor0_.basket_id ,className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket}}
DEBUG FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  o.basket -> purchaseor0_.basket_id
DEBUG HqlSqlWalker - createFromJoinElement() : -- join tree --
 \-[JOIN_FRAGMENT] FromElement: 'shoppingbaskets shoppingba1_' FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=null,role=null,tableName=shoppingbaskets,tableAlias=shoppingba1_,origin=purchaseorders purchaseor0_,columns={purchaseor0_.basket_id ,className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket}}

DEBUG FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  o -> purchaseor0_.id
DEBUG DotNode - getDataType() : statusE -> org.hibernate.type.CustomType@493744b6
DEBUG FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  o.statusE -> purchaseor0_.status
DEBUG FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  o -> purchaseor0_.id
DEBUG DotNode - getDataType() : created -> org.hibernate.type.TimestampType@69a4e343
DEBUG FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  o.created -> purchaseor0_.created
DEBUG HqlSqlBaseWalker - select : finishing up [level=1, statement=select]
DEBUG HqlSqlWalker - processQuery() :  ( SELECT ( FromClause{level=1} ( purchaseorders purchaseor0_ shoppingbaskets shoppingba1_ ) ) ( where ( in ( purchaseor0_.status purchaseor0_.id statusE ) ( inList ? ) ) ) ( ORDER ( purchaseor0_.created purchaseor0_.id created ) DESC ) )
DEBUG HqlSqlWalker - Derived SELECT clause created.
DEBUG JoinProcessor - Using FROM fragment [purchaseorders purchaseor0_]
DEBUG JoinProcessor - Using FROM fragment [inner join shoppingbaskets shoppingba1_ on purchaseor0_.basket_id=shoppingba1_.id]
DEBUG HqlSqlBaseWalker - select >> end [level=1, statement=select]
DEBUG AST - --- SQL AST ---
 \-[SELECT] QueryNode: 'SELECT'  querySpaces (purchaseorders,shoppingbaskets)
    +-[SELECT_CLAUSE] SelectClause: '{derived select clause}'
    |  +-[SELECT_EXPR] SelectExpressionImpl: 'purchaseor0_.id as id10_0_' {FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=o,role=null,tableName=purchaseorders,tableAlias=purchaseor0_,origin=null,columns={,className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder}}}
    |  +-[SELECT_EXPR] SelectExpressionImpl: 'shoppingba1_.id as id9_1_' {FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=null,role=null,tableName=shoppingbaskets,tableAlias=shoppingba1_,origin=purchaseorders purchaseor0_,columns={purchaseor0_.basket_id ,className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket}}}
    |  +-[SQL_TOKEN] SqlFragment: 'purchaseor0_.address_id as address17_10_0_, purchaseor0_.affiliate_id as affiliate18_10_0_, purchaseor0_.agreed_cardholder as agreed2_10_0_, purchaseor0_.agreed_terms as agreed3_10_0_, purchaseor0_.alternativeCustomerName as alternat4_10_0_, purchaseor0_.approved as approved10_0_, purchaseor0_.author as author10_0_, purchaseor0_.basket_id as basket19_10_0_, purchaseor0_.card_id as card20_10_0_, purchaseor0_.created as created10_0_, purchaseor0_.editor as editor10_0_, purchaseor0_.groupBookingId as groupBo21_10_0_, purchaseor0_.ip_address as ip9_10_0_, purchaseor0_.linkedOrder as linkedO22_10_0_, purchaseor0_.manual_hold as manual10_10_0_, purchaseor0_.manual_review as manual11_10_0_, purchaseor0_.partner_id as partner23_10_0_, purchaseor0_.platformType as platfor12_10_0_, purchaseor0_.reference as reference10_0_, purchaseor0_.status as status10_0_, purchaseor0_.updated as updated10_0_, purchaseor0_.user_id as user24_10_0_, purchaseor0_.views as views10_0_'
    |  \-[SQL_TOKEN] SqlFragment: 'shoppingba1_.call_center as call2_9_1_, shoppingba1_.call_center_fee as call3_9_1_, shoppingba1_.cardCharge as cardCharge9_1_, shoppingba1_.created as created9_1_, shoppingba1_.currency as currency9_1_, shoppingba1_.deliveryCost as delivery6_9_1_, shoppingba1_.delivery_option as delivery14_9_1_, shoppingba1_.deliveryType as delivery7_9_1_, shoppingba1_.insurance as insurance9_1_, shoppingba1_.owner as owner9_1_, shoppingba1_.promotionCode_id as promoti15_9_1_, shoppingba1_.status as status9_1_, shoppingba1_.unique_id as unique11_9_1_, shoppingba1_.updated as updated9_1_'
    +-[FROM] FromClause: 'from' FromClause{level=1, fromElementCounter=2, fromElements=2, fromElementByClassAlias=[o], fromElementByTableAlias=[purchaseor0_, shoppingba1_], fromElementsByPath=[o.basket], collectionJoinFromElementsByPath=[], impliedElements=[]}
    |  \-[FROM_FRAGMENT] FromElement: 'purchaseorders purchaseor0_' FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=o,role=null,tableName=purchaseorders,tableAlias=purchaseor0_,origin=null,columns={,className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder}}
    |     \-[JOIN_FRAGMENT] FromElement: 'inner join shoppingbaskets shoppingba1_ on purchaseor0_.basket_id=shoppingba1_.id' FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=null,role=null,tableName=shoppingbaskets,tableAlias=shoppingba1_,origin=purchaseorders purchaseor0_,columns={purchaseor0_.basket_id ,className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket}}
    +-[WHERE] SqlNode: 'where'
    |  \-[IN] InLogicOperatorNode: 'in'
    |     +-[DOT] DotNode: 'purchaseor0_.status' {propertyName=statusE,dereferenceType=ALL,propertyPath=statusE,path=o.statusE,tableAlias=purchaseor0_,className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder,classAlias=o}
    |     |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'purchaseor0_.id' {alias=o, className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder, tableAlias=purchaseor0_}
    |     |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'statusE' {originalText=statusE}
    |     \-[IN_LIST] SqlNode: 'inList'
    |        \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=statuses, expectedType=org.hibernate.type.CustomType@493744b6}
    \-[ORDER] OrderByClause: 'ORDER'
       +-[DOT] DotNode: 'purchaseor0_.created' {propertyName=created,dereferenceType=ALL,propertyPath=created,path=o.created,tableAlias=purchaseor0_,className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder,classAlias=o}
       |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'purchaseor0_.id' {alias=o, className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder, tableAlias=purchaseor0_}
       |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'created' {originalText=created}
       \-[DESCENDING] SqlNode: 'DESC'

DEBUG ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
DEBUG QueryTranslatorImpl - HQL: from com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder o join fetch o.basket where o.statusE in (:statuses) ORDER BY o.created DESC
DEBUG QueryTranslatorImpl - SQL: select purchaseor0_.id as id10_0_, shoppingba1_.id as id9_1_, purchaseor0_.address_id as address17_10_0_, purchaseor0_.affiliate_id as affiliate18_10_0_, purchaseor0_.agreed_cardholder as agreed2_10_0_, purchaseor0_.agreed_terms as agreed3_10_0_, purchaseor0_.alternativeCustomerName as alternat4_10_0_, purchaseor0_.approved as approved10_0_, purchaseor0_.author as author10_0_, purchaseor0_.basket_id as basket19_10_0_, purchaseor0_.card_id as card20_10_0_, purchaseor0_.created as created10_0_, purchaseor0_.editor as editor10_0_, purchaseor0_.groupBookingId as groupBo21_10_0_, purchaseor0_.ip_address as ip9_10_0_, purchaseor0_.linkedOrder as linkedO22_10_0_, purchaseor0_.manual_hold as manual10_10_0_, purchaseor0_.manual_review as manual11_10_0_, purchaseor0_.partner_id as partner23_10_0_, purchaseor0_.platformType as platfor12_10_0_, purchaseor0_.reference as reference10_0_, purchaseor0_.status as status10_0_, purchaseor0_.updated as updated10_0_, purchaseor0_.user_id as user24_10_0_, purchaseor0_.views as views10_0_, shoppingba1_.call_center as call2_9_1_, shoppingba1_.call_center_fee as call3_9_1_, shoppingba1_.cardCharge as cardCharge9_1_, shoppingba1_.created as created9_1_, shoppingba1_.currency as currency9_1_, shoppingba1_.deliveryCost as delivery6_9_1_, shoppingba1_.delivery_option as delivery14_9_1_, shoppingba1_.deliveryType as delivery7_9_1_, shoppingba1_.insurance as insurance9_1_, shoppingba1_.owner as owner9_1_, shoppingba1_.promotionCode_id as promoti15_9_1_, shoppingba1_.status as status9_1_, shoppingba1_.unique_id as unique11_9_1_, shoppingba1_.updated as updated9_1_ from purchaseorders purchaseor0_ inner join shoppingbaskets shoppingba1_ on purchaseor0_.basket_id=shoppingba1_.id where purchaseor0_.status in (?) order by purchaseor0_.created DESC
DEBUG ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
DEBUG QueryTranslatorImpl - parse() - HQL: from com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder o join fetch o.basket where o.statusE in (:statuses0_, :statuses1_, :statuses2_) ORDER BY o.created DESC
DEBUG AST - --- HQL AST ---
 \-[QUERY] Node: 'query'
    +-[SELECT_FROM] Node: 'SELECT_FROM'
    |  \-[FROM] Node: 'from'
    |     +-[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
    |     |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |     |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |     |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |     |  |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |     |  |  |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |     |  |  |  |  |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'com'
    |     |  |  |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'ng'
    |     |  |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'ticketlogic'
    |     |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'core'
    |     |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'shop'
    |     |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'PurchaseOrder'
    |     |  \-[ALIAS] Node: 'o'
    |     \-[JOIN] Node: 'join'
    |        +-[FETCH] Node: 'fetch'
    |        \-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |           +-[IDENT] Node: 'o'
    |           \-[IDENT] Node: 'basket'
    +-[WHERE] Node: 'where'
    |  \-[IN] Node: 'in'
    |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |     |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'o'
    |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'statusE'
    |     \-[IN_LIST] Node: 'inList'
    |        +-[COLON] Node: ':'
    |        |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'statuses0_'
    |        +-[COLON] Node: ':'
    |        |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'statuses1_'
    |        \-[COLON] Node: ':'
    |           \-[IDENT] Node: 'statuses2_'
    \-[ORDER] Node: 'ORDER'
       +-[DOT] Node: '.'
       |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'o'
       |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'created'
       \-[DESCENDING] Node: 'DESC'

DEBUG ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
DEBUG HqlSqlBaseWalker - select << begin [level=1, statement=select]
DEBUG FromElement - FromClause{level=1} :  com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder (o) -> purchaseor0_
DEBUG FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  o -> purchaseor0_.id
DEBUG DotNode - getDataType() : basket -> org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType(com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket)
DEBUG DotNode - dereferenceEntityJoin() : generating join for basket in com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder {no alias} parent = [ {null} ]
DEBUG FromElement - FromClause{level=1} :  com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket (no alias) -> shoppingba1_
DEBUG FromClause - addJoinByPathMap() : o.basket -> FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=null,role=null,tableName=shoppingbaskets,tableAlias=shoppingba1_,origin=purchaseorders purchaseor0_,columns={purchaseor0_.basket_id ,className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket}}
DEBUG FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  o.basket -> purchaseor0_.basket_id
DEBUG HqlSqlWalker - createFromJoinElement() : -- join tree --
 \-[JOIN_FRAGMENT] FromElement: 'shoppingbaskets shoppingba1_' FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=null,role=null,tableName=shoppingbaskets,tableAlias=shoppingba1_,origin=purchaseorders purchaseor0_,columns={purchaseor0_.basket_id ,className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket}}

DEBUG FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  o -> purchaseor0_.id
DEBUG DotNode - getDataType() : statusE -> org.hibernate.type.CustomType@493744b6
DEBUG FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  o.statusE -> purchaseor0_.status
DEBUG FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  o -> purchaseor0_.id
DEBUG DotNode - getDataType() : created -> org.hibernate.type.TimestampType@69a4e343
DEBUG FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  o.created -> purchaseor0_.created
DEBUG HqlSqlBaseWalker - select : finishing up [level=1, statement=select]
DEBUG HqlSqlWalker - processQuery() :  ( SELECT ( FromClause{level=1} ( purchaseorders purchaseor0_ shoppingbaskets shoppingba1_ ) ) ( where ( in ( purchaseor0_.status purchaseor0_.id statusE ) ( inList ? ? ? ) ) ) ( ORDER ( purchaseor0_.created purchaseor0_.id created ) DESC ) )
DEBUG HqlSqlWalker - Derived SELECT clause created.
DEBUG JoinProcessor - Using FROM fragment [purchaseorders purchaseor0_]
DEBUG JoinProcessor - Using FROM fragment [inner join shoppingbaskets shoppingba1_ on purchaseor0_.basket_id=shoppingba1_.id]
DEBUG HqlSqlBaseWalker - select >> end [level=1, statement=select]
DEBUG AST - --- SQL AST ---
 \-[SELECT] QueryNode: 'SELECT'  querySpaces (purchaseorders,shoppingbaskets)
    +-[SELECT_CLAUSE] SelectClause: '{derived select clause}'
    |  +-[SELECT_EXPR] SelectExpressionImpl: 'purchaseor0_.id as id10_0_' {FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=o,role=null,tableName=purchaseorders,tableAlias=purchaseor0_,origin=null,columns={,className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder}}}
    |  +-[SELECT_EXPR] SelectExpressionImpl: 'shoppingba1_.id as id9_1_' {FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=null,role=null,tableName=shoppingbaskets,tableAlias=shoppingba1_,origin=purchaseorders purchaseor0_,columns={purchaseor0_.basket_id ,className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket}}}
    |  +-[SQL_TOKEN] SqlFragment: 'purchaseor0_.address_id as address17_10_0_, purchaseor0_.affiliate_id as affiliate18_10_0_, purchaseor0_.agreed_cardholder as agreed2_10_0_, purchaseor0_.agreed_terms as agreed3_10_0_, purchaseor0_.alternativeCustomerName as alternat4_10_0_, purchaseor0_.approved as approved10_0_, purchaseor0_.author as author10_0_, purchaseor0_.basket_id as basket19_10_0_, purchaseor0_.card_id as card20_10_0_, purchaseor0_.created as created10_0_, purchaseor0_.editor as editor10_0_, purchaseor0_.groupBookingId as groupBo21_10_0_, purchaseor0_.ip_address as ip9_10_0_, purchaseor0_.linkedOrder as linkedO22_10_0_, purchaseor0_.manual_hold as manual10_10_0_, purchaseor0_.manual_review as manual11_10_0_, purchaseor0_.partner_id as partner23_10_0_, purchaseor0_.platformType as platfor12_10_0_, purchaseor0_.reference as reference10_0_, purchaseor0_.status as status10_0_, purchaseor0_.updated as updated10_0_, purchaseor0_.user_id as user24_10_0_, purchaseor0_.views as views10_0_'
    |  \-[SQL_TOKEN] SqlFragment: 'shoppingba1_.call_center as call2_9_1_, shoppingba1_.call_center_fee as call3_9_1_, shoppingba1_.cardCharge as cardCharge9_1_, shoppingba1_.created as created9_1_, shoppingba1_.currency as currency9_1_, shoppingba1_.deliveryCost as delivery6_9_1_, shoppingba1_.delivery_option as delivery14_9_1_, shoppingba1_.deliveryType as delivery7_9_1_, shoppingba1_.insurance as insurance9_1_, shoppingba1_.owner as owner9_1_, shoppingba1_.promotionCode_id as promoti15_9_1_, shoppingba1_.status as status9_1_, shoppingba1_.unique_id as unique11_9_1_, shoppingba1_.updated as updated9_1_'
    +-[FROM] FromClause: 'from' FromClause{level=1, fromElementCounter=2, fromElements=2, fromElementByClassAlias=[o], fromElementByTableAlias=[purchaseor0_, shoppingba1_], fromElementsByPath=[o.basket], collectionJoinFromElementsByPath=[], impliedElements=[]}
    |  \-[FROM_FRAGMENT] FromElement: 'purchaseorders purchaseor0_' FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=o,role=null,tableName=purchaseorders,tableAlias=purchaseor0_,origin=null,columns={,className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder}}
    |     \-[JOIN_FRAGMENT] FromElement: 'inner join shoppingbaskets shoppingba1_ on purchaseor0_.basket_id=shoppingba1_.id' FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=null,role=null,tableName=shoppingbaskets,tableAlias=shoppingba1_,origin=purchaseorders purchaseor0_,columns={purchaseor0_.basket_id ,className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket}}
    +-[WHERE] SqlNode: 'where'
    |  \-[IN] InLogicOperatorNode: 'in'
    |     +-[DOT] DotNode: 'purchaseor0_.status' {propertyName=statusE,dereferenceType=ALL,propertyPath=statusE,path=o.statusE,tableAlias=purchaseor0_,className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder,classAlias=o}
    |     |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'purchaseor0_.id' {alias=o, className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder, tableAlias=purchaseor0_}
    |     |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'statusE' {originalText=statusE}
    |     \-[IN_LIST] SqlNode: 'inList'
    |        +-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=statuses0_, expectedType=org.hibernate.type.CustomType@493744b6}
    |        +-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=statuses1_, expectedType=org.hibernate.type.CustomType@493744b6}
    |        \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=statuses2_, expectedType=org.hibernate.type.CustomType@493744b6}
    \-[ORDER] OrderByClause: 'ORDER'
       +-[DOT] DotNode: 'purchaseor0_.created' {propertyName=created,dereferenceType=ALL,propertyPath=created,path=o.created,tableAlias=purchaseor0_,className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder,classAlias=o}
       |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'purchaseor0_.id' {alias=o, className=com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder, tableAlias=purchaseor0_}
       |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'created' {originalText=created}
       \-[DESCENDING] SqlNode: 'DESC'

DEBUG ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
DEBUG QueryTranslatorImpl - HQL: from com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder o join fetch o.basket where o.statusE in (:statuses0_, :statuses1_, :statuses2_) ORDER BY o.created DESC
DEBUG QueryTranslatorImpl - SQL: select purchaseor0_.id as id10_0_, shoppingba1_.id as id9_1_, purchaseor0_.address_id as address17_10_0_, purchaseor0_.affiliate_id as affiliate18_10_0_, purchaseor0_.agreed_cardholder as agreed2_10_0_, purchaseor0_.agreed_terms as agreed3_10_0_, purchaseor0_.alternativeCustomerName as alternat4_10_0_, purchaseor0_.approved as approved10_0_, purchaseor0_.author as author10_0_, purchaseor0_.basket_id as basket19_10_0_, purchaseor0_.card_id as card20_10_0_, purchaseor0_.created as created10_0_, purchaseor0_.editor as editor10_0_, purchaseor0_.groupBookingId as groupBo21_10_0_, purchaseor0_.ip_address as ip9_10_0_, purchaseor0_.linkedOrder as linkedO22_10_0_, purchaseor0_.manual_hold as manual10_10_0_, purchaseor0_.manual_review as manual11_10_0_, purchaseor0_.partner_id as partner23_10_0_, purchaseor0_.platformType as platfor12_10_0_, purchaseor0_.reference as reference10_0_, purchaseor0_.status as status10_0_, purchaseor0_.updated as updated10_0_, purchaseor0_.user_id as user24_10_0_, purchaseor0_.views as views10_0_, shoppingba1_.call_center as call2_9_1_, shoppingba1_.call_center_fee as call3_9_1_, shoppingba1_.cardCharge as cardCharge9_1_, shoppingba1_.created as created9_1_, shoppingba1_.currency as currency9_1_, shoppingba1_.deliveryCost as delivery6_9_1_, shoppingba1_.delivery_option as delivery14_9_1_, shoppingba1_.deliveryType as delivery7_9_1_, shoppingba1_.insurance as insurance9_1_, shoppingba1_.owner as owner9_1_, shoppingba1_.promotionCode_id as promoti15_9_1_, shoppingba1_.status as status9_1_, shoppingba1_.unique_id as unique11_9_1_, shoppingba1_.updated as updated9_1_ from purchaseorders purchaseor0_ inner join shoppingbaskets shoppingba1_ on purchaseor0_.basket_id=shoppingba1_.id where purchaseor0_.status in (? , ? , ?) order by purchaseor0_.created DESC
DEBUG ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
DEBUG AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
DEBUG SQL - select purchaseor0_.id as id10_0_, shoppingba1_.id as id9_1_, purchaseor0_.address_id as address17_10_0_, purchaseor0_.affiliate_id as affiliate18_10_0_, purchaseor0_.agreed_cardholder as agreed2_10_0_, purchaseor0_.agreed_terms as agreed3_10_0_, purchaseor0_.alternativeCustomerName as alternat4_10_0_, purchaseor0_.approved as approved10_0_, purchaseor0_.author as author10_0_, purchaseor0_.basket_id as basket19_10_0_, purchaseor0_.card_id as card20_10_0_, purchaseor0_.created as created10_0_, purchaseor0_.editor as editor10_0_, purchaseor0_.groupBookingId as groupBo21_10_0_, purchaseor0_.ip_address as ip9_10_0_, purchaseor0_.linkedOrder as linkedO22_10_0_, purchaseor0_.manual_hold as manual10_10_0_, purchaseor0_.manual_review as manual11_10_0_, purchaseor0_.partner_id as partner23_10_0_, purchaseor0_.platformType as platfor12_10_0_, purchaseor0_.reference as reference10_0_, purchaseor0_.status as status10_0_, purchaseor0_.updated as updated10_0_, purchaseor0_.user_id as user24_10_0_, purchaseor0_.views as views10_0_, shoppingba1_.call_center as call2_9_1_, shoppingba1_.call_center_fee as call3_9_1_, shoppingba1_.cardCharge as cardCharge9_1_, shoppingba1_.created as created9_1_, shoppingba1_.currency as currency9_1_, shoppingba1_.deliveryCost as delivery6_9_1_, shoppingba1_.delivery_option as delivery14_9_1_, shoppingba1_.deliveryType as delivery7_9_1_, shoppingba1_.insurance as insurance9_1_, shoppingba1_.owner as owner9_1_, shoppingba1_.promotionCode_id as promoti15_9_1_, shoppingba1_.status as status9_1_, shoppingba1_.unique_id as unique11_9_1_, shoppingba1_.updated as updated9_1_ from purchaseorders purchaseor0_ inner join shoppingbaskets shoppingba1_ on purchaseor0_.basket_id=shoppingba1_.id where purchaseor0_.status in (? , ? , ?) order by purchaseor0_.created DESC limit ?
DEBUG AbstractBatcher - about to open ResultSet (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
DEBUG Loader - result row: EntityKey[com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder#615430], EntityKey[com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket#1608284]
DEBUG Loader - result row: EntityKey[com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder#614920], EntityKey[com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket#1607774]
DEBUG Loader - result row: EntityKey[com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder#614875], EntityKey[com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket#1607729]
DEBUG Loader - result row: EntityKey[com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder#610567], EntityKey[com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket#1603430]
DEBUG Loader - result row: EntityKey[com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder#608160], EntityKey[com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket#1601039]
DEBUG Loader - result row: EntityKey[com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder#601660], EntityKey[com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket#1594566]
DEBUG AbstractBatcher - about to close ResultSet (open ResultSets: 1, globally: 1)
DEBUG AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad - resolving associations for [com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder#615430]
DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad - done materializing entity [com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder#615430]
DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad - resolving associations for [com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket#1608284]
DEBUG Loader - loading entity: [com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder#1608284]
DEBUG AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
DEBUG SQL - select purchaseor0_.id as id10_0_, purchaseor0_.address_id as address17_10_0_, purchaseor0_.affiliate_id as affiliate18_10_0_, purchaseor0_.agreed_cardholder as agreed2_10_0_, purchaseor0_.agreed_terms as agreed3_10_0_, purchaseor0_.alternativeCustomerName as alternat4_10_0_, purchaseor0_.approved as approved10_0_, purchaseor0_.author as author10_0_, purchaseor0_.basket_id as basket19_10_0_, purchaseor0_.card_id as card20_10_0_, purchaseor0_.created as created10_0_, purchaseor0_.editor as editor10_0_, purchaseor0_.groupBookingId as groupBo21_10_0_, purchaseor0_.ip_address as ip9_10_0_, purchaseor0_.linkedOrder as linkedO22_10_0_, purchaseor0_.manual_hold as manual10_10_0_, purchaseor0_.manual_review as manual11_10_0_, purchaseor0_.partner_id as partner23_10_0_, purchaseor0_.platformType as platfor12_10_0_, purchaseor0_.reference as reference10_0_, purchaseor0_.status as status10_0_, purchaseor0_.updated as updated10_0_, purchaseor0_.user_id as user24_10_0_, purchaseor0_.views as views10_0_ from purchaseorders purchaseor0_ where purchaseor0_.basket_id=?
DEBUG AbstractBatcher - about to open ResultSet (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
DEBUG Loader - result row: EntityKey[com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.PurchaseOrder#615430]
DEBUG AbstractBatcher - about to close ResultSet (open ResultSets: 1, globally: 1)
DEBUG AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
DEBUG Loader - done entity load
DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad - done materializing entity [com.ng.ticketlogic.core.shop.ShoppingBasket#1608284]
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. I have plans for changing the structure of that part completely, but at the moment I'm stuck with this problem. Hibernate doesn't play nice with OneToOne relationships

Answer (score 2):

[Using `FetchMode.JOIN` disables LAZY loading.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e3756) The resulting behaviour might not be what you expect. 
Try this:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name="basket_id")
public ShoppingBasket getBasket() {
    return this.basket;
}

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "basket", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
public PurchaseOrder getOrder() {
    return order;
}
```

After that, your query will result on only single DB query being executed.  Result will contain a list of PurchaseOrder objects, each with a correctly initialized basket attribute.

As a side note: is a bidirectional, mutually required, one-to-one relationship really required? From a business point of view, purchase order is created after the lifecycle of shopping basket, therefore it does not nee a reference to it(it should contain a list of order items created based on the contents of basket). But that is a just a suggestion.